# React - How can I make one time only rendering value in state

Tags: reactjs

What I need to do is to **setState** with a value, then send data to a children by props, but I would like "state" to forget about that after doing this once.

```
this.setState({ 
    animateId: 15 //or any number of id
});
```

then later

```
if(this.state.animateId){
   let idToSent = this.state.animateId;
}
<Items <...different props> animate={idToSent}/> //once after settingState - 15, 
                                        // then undefined or whatever with every next time
```

and I would want to take this value once, send it via props, and forget about it, either way.

Is there any way to do that, beside just altering that one value in state again, because that would cause unnecesary rendering ??

Comment: Do you want your component to re-render just when you are setting doSomething to true and not when setting it to false?

Comment: @EddieCooro No, it's only about value sent in one of a prop. It has to be only once, because it's about animating item I don't want it to animate it over and over again.

Comment: can you show a full reproducible code of the problem?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I changed few things to show more what I was talking about.

Comment: well, the thing is it depends on your intention if you intend to initially show the state with `animateId`, then you can just initialize it in `constructor` and in `componentDidMount` you can `if (this.state.animateId) { this.setState({animatedId: false}) }`

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I can't. All components involved are already mounted, they don't unmount at all, and setState is also adding new item, keeping id to animate and I'd like to find a way to communicate a child once, when parent added new item, but not store that id ever again, cause any other action would keep sending that id and it would animate again.

Answer (score 0):

We can set it to undefined like this after our task is complete

`this.setState({ doSomething: undefined });`

Comment: Yeah, I know it. I would prefer to set it to "false", but the key in that case is to not set state again and rerender whole application again.

Answer (score 0):

I would let the `Item` component keep track of when and when not to initiate the animation based on comparing the latest props with the local state.

I don't know exactly how you are triggering the animation, but it sound like you could do something like this in the `Item` component

```
const { animateId } = this.props;

if (animateId !== this.state.animateId) {
  // Whatever code that starts your animation...

  // Then either update the state right away to signal the last animation
  // that was triggered, or if it can't be done here, then set it in a 
  // callback from when the animation is done.
  this.setState({ animateId });
}
```

Just keep in mind that if this code is executed during the `render` phase, then it probably won't let you call setState.

Comment: I'm trying to keep children components stateless, also settingState after animation will cause rerendering. I don't technically need to use state, I need one way communication parent -> child, one time, then forget about whole thing, There is no other way in react, than 2 steps - setState with a value, then unset that value ??

Comment: In that case, maybe use the lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare previous props with nextProps and if they have the same `animateId` then return false which will prevent it from re-rendering. I can give an example later but am on mobile right now

Comment: Actually this component should update in every case, additionaly problem would still persist, because "animateId" would still be set in state of a parent component, therefore resend with every minor state change. What I need is to make "animateID" be present only once in parent component, render and sent via prop to a child, and somehow make it dissapear after 1 cycle and not store it's value anywhere, anymore. Kinda like forgetabble/temporary state value that exists only with 1 cycle, and not exist after that. Every next "render()" doesn't know that value even existed. Any way to do that ??

Comment: I'm sorry but now you are contradicting yourself. First you say that you don't want it to re-render. Then you say that it should update in every case. You have two ways of keeping track of the animateId, one is state (which you don't want to use) and the other is props. And you want to change the props but not re-render the child component when that happens. If you want more ideas, then I would suggest that you show how exactly you are using the animateId in the Item component.

Comment: I don't want this one value "animateId" from parent state that will be sent via prop to be kept and resend with every state change, but child component should be rerender every single time. Action leading to setState with animateID, after that- 1st cycle- prop has value of animateID, then unrelated action causing state change- 2nd cycle- same prop is undefined, not exist of whatever, 3rd cycle -same, but child rerenders every time, it's all about this value, to be existing only once, and not exist after 1 cycle, prop stil will be send, but without any action provoking value, like undeff/null.

Comment: Okay, so how about just simply using `componentDidUpdate` in the parent component and if `animateId` in state is not null, then set it to null? That would allow you to handle it all in the parent component. As soon as something sets it to any value, it triggers a render cycle, and when it is complete, you reset it. Would that fulfill your requirements?

Comment: Thanks, this is the best suggestion so far, but I've recently solved my problem by creating boolean variable in parent's constructor and control what to sent that way.